# Issue with CSS coloring the inside of a radio

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to color the inside of my radio button when its checked, so I have this html:

```
<div class="form-check">
  <label>
    <input
      class="form-check-input"
      type="radio"
      name="myradio">
    Text here
  </label>
</div>
```

And this css:

```
.form-control-input:checked~.form-control-label::before {
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #7B1FA2;
}
```

The above css is not coloring it.

How can I do this?

Comment: You want to change the default color `blue` to something else? if that the case I doubt you can do it, those are dependent on OS,

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I need

Comment: Check if this helps: https://dev.to/kallmanation/styling-a-radio-button-with-only-css-4llc